# Scale geom_point() size to increase size based on distance from zero

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot some measures that have been standardized to z-scores. I want the size of the point in geom_point() to increase from 0 to 3, and also to increase from 0 to -3. I also want the colour to change from red, to blue. The trick is to get both to work together.

Here is an example that's as close as I can get to what I'd like, note that the size of the point increases from -2, whereas I want the size of the point to increase as the z_score moves away from zero.

```
library(tidyverse)

year <- rep(c(2015:2018), each = 3)
parameters <- rep(c("length", "weight", "condition"), 4)
z_score <- runif(12, min = -2, max = 2)
df <- tibble(year, parameters, z_score)

cols <- c("#d73027",
          "darkgrey",
          "#4575b4")

ggplot(df, aes(year, parameters, colour = z_score, size = z_score)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = cols) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  scale_size(range = c(1,15)) +
  guides(color= guide_legend(), size=guide_legend())
```

[bubble plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L73s9.png)

One trick I tried was to use the absolute value of z_score which scaled the points correctly but messed up the legend.

Here's what I'd like the legend and points size to be scaled to, though I'd like the colour to be a gradient as in my example. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

[Link to plot legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPhdr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close.  In order to adjust the size of the points in the legend, use the override.aes option in the `guides` function.

```
library(ggplot2)
year <- rep(c(2015:2018), each = 3)
parameters <- rep(c("length", "weight", "condition"), 4)
z_score <- runif(12, min = -2, max = 2)
df <- tibble(year, parameters, z_score)

cols <- c("#d73027",  "darkgrey",  "#4575b4")

ggplot(df, aes(year, parameters, colour = z_score)) +
  geom_point( size=abs(5*df$z_score)) +   # times 5 to increase size
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = cols) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  scale_size(range = c(1,15)) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = c( 5, 1, 5))) )
```

[image]

In order to suppress the legend being print for the size attribute, I moved it outside the aes, field.  This works for this example, one will have to adjust the size=c(...) to match the number of division in the legend.

This should answer your question and get you most of the way there on answering your question.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. I think scale_size() is now meaningless, I guess because it's being over written. I wonder then if there is a way to increase the minimum point size now?

Comment: The size of the point is based on this statement: `geom_point( size=abs(5*df$z_score)) ` , so to change the size of point you could add a factor to the z_score before the multiplier factor or some similar combination.